# How to manage wordpress pages menu from database?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

How to find where my page titles exists in my database and how to merge with my menus? Maybe I can easily change them using phpmyadmin?

I found that Apearance->Menus is a nightmare when i have more than 40+ menu items. I want to get a workaround idea?

Comment: Is that possible that my issue is, work on remote server?

Answer (score 0):

The menu items in the list are derived from each page's title. If you want to create a custom menu editor, use [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). It also helps to make sure that you set each page's parent page.

It might pay to look for a menu editor plugin, as I am sure they exist (No I havn't looked).

Comment: I looked all plugins, paid ones, but it becomes extremely slow after 40+ menu items... So i want to find faster way to set my setings for menu.

Comment: The time it will take you to write a plugin is a bit of a trade-off against the time to edit the menu's, even if it is painful. In theory this should be something you only do once off.

Comment: In wordpress comunity i found that problem will be fixed in version 3.8, but now in version 4.1 it still... I have more than 3 wordpress pages in month with huge menu item count, so i need tutorial, guides how to start looking how to solve, possible solution ideas, anything that would help.

Comment: I see your problem. Take a look at http://jamocreations.com/en/artikelen/auto-submenu and see if it helps. If automatically adds child pages as a sub- menu the same way root pages can already be added to a menu.

Comment: Can anyone show and explain how to do it directly on my database? Where to look for page titles and dependences to menus?

Comment: The page titles are in wp_posts. There is a column called post_title, and post_parent. post_type will be 'page' and post_status will be 'publish'. Then you will get a full list of pages, with it's parent id.

Comment: The menu item is derived from the menu title. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-help-where-is-the-nav-menu-stored

Comment: I found that in my database. Next, what is the easiest way to get out of that number in my database, becouse its really hard to identify, where my pages are. I expected, that everything is saved like:
menu_title, level_of depth and etc, but i found only lots of numbers.